# Read number from file into a 2D matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to write a function to read number from a file into a 2D matrix; `mm_alloc()` function is a function that creates an empty matrix, and
the first line of this file is the size of the matrix; but code seems can not read from the file, what is my problem? Do I use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` wrongly?

```
double **mm_alloc( int size )
{
    double **matrix;
    int i;
    matrix = (double **)malloc((size) * sizeof(double *));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        matrix[i] = (double *)malloc(size);
    }
    return( matrix );
}


double **mm_read( char *filename, int *size ) 
{
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    char read[256];
    fgets(read, 256, myfile);
    sscanf(read, "%d", size);
    int i, j;
    double **Matrix;
    Matrix = mm_alloc( *size );
    for ( i = 0; i < *size; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < *size; j++) {
            fgets(read, 256, myfile);
            sscanf(read, "%lf", &Matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose (myfile);
    return( Matrix );
}

void mm_free( int size, double **matrix  )
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

void mm_print( int size, double **matrix )
{
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
            printf("%16f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

double **mm_swap( int size, double **matrix ) 
{
    double **swap;
    swap = mm_alloc(size);
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < (size-2); j++) {
            swap[i][j] = matrix[i][j+2];
            swap[i][j+2] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return( swap );
}

double **mm_matrix_mult( int size, double **matrix, double **transpose )
{
    double **matrix_mult;
    matrix_mult = mm_alloc(size);
    int i, j, k;
    double result;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
            result = 0;
            for ( k = 0; k < size; k++ ) {
                result += (matrix[i][k] * transpose[k][j]);
            }
            matrix_mult[i][j] = result;
        }
    }
    return( matrix_mult );
}

int main()
{
    char filename[256];
    double **matrix=NULL;
    double **swap_matrix=NULL;
    double **results_matrix=NULL;
    int size=0;

    printf("Please enter the matrix data file name: ");
    scanf( "%s", filename );

    matrix = mm_read( filename, &size );
    swap_matrix = mm_swap( size, matrix ); 
    results_matrix = mm_matrix_mult( size, matrix, swap_matrix );

    mm_print( size, results_matrix );
    mm_free( size, matrix );
    mm_free( size, swap_matrix );
    mm_free( size, results_matrix );
    return( 0 ); 
}
```

**the file content:**

```
4
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
11.0
12.0
13.0
14.0
15.0
16.0
```

Comment: **Always** check return values of all I/O functions!

Comment: "*but code seems can not read from the file*" you conclude this from what, please?

Comment: Show the first lines of the file you read.

Comment: Note that question is missing a lot of information. Please read on how to provide [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Seems you are using a C++ compiler. If not remove all those casts, as they are useless in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file with "w".

That will erase the file. You need to open with "r" to read from a file.

Answer (score 1):

You allocation function allocates to few memory.

This line

```
    matrix[i] = (double *)malloc(size);
```

should at least be

```
    matrix[i] = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));
```

Or even better removing this useless cast:

```
    matrix[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(double));
```

---

Also the allocation function fully missed to perform any error checking. `malloc() might very well fail, depending of the size of memory requested.

Below please find a safe implementation:

```
/* Allocates a pointer matrix to an array of size pointers
   each pointing to size doubles.

   Returns matrix or NULL on error. 
 */

double ** mm_alloc(size_t size)
{
  double ** matrix =  malloc(size * sizeof *matrix);
  if (NULL != matrix) 
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
      matrix[i] = malloc(size * sizeof *matrix[i]);
      if (NULL == matrix[i])
      {  /* Clean up. */
        while (0 < i)
        {
          --i;
          free(matrix[i]);
        }

        free(matrix);
        matrix = NULL;

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return matrix;
}
```

Comment: i have changed it, but it seems still not working; i have used fscanf() instead of fgets() and sscanf(); fscanf() works, but  fgets() and sscanf() do not.

Comment: @HaotianSong: You want to go for tracing the code using a debugger.